# What are the advantages of implementing an optimization algorithm for PID tuning compared to classical methods?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, optimization, algorithm

I am new to studying algorithms, so I am wondering what are the advantages of using an algorithm such as Genetic Algorithm or PSO to tune the PID parameters compared to classical methods, such as Ziegler-Nichols?

Comment: (Anyone remember [*fuzzy*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_control_system)?)

Comment: Actually I am working on this subject right now. Ziegler-Nichols method is an experimental method, you obtain the parameters by trying. On the other hand, genetic algorithm is an optimization method. It generally gives you the best solution in the solution space. But it is unnecessary for simple systems.

Comment: I am always cautious with it comes down to PID tuning,  First off, a classical PID does not offer a good noise immunity as the two zeroes make the gain increase at high frequency. The *filtered* PID is a better option in my opinion and, if you add another pole, you have a type 3 commonly used in loop control of switching converters. Back to PID, I prefer placing adequate poles and zeroes then convert these into \$k_p\$, \$k_d\$, \$k_i\$ and \$N\$. Honestly, I don't see myself applying Ziegler-Nichols to a multi-kW converter and push \$k_p\$ until the output oscillates : )